# Define Roles in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a business website for my own use.
I have two kind of user 
1. Admin-> Complete navigational rights
2. User-> Hides some navigational menu.

and I've defined these in authentication table in the database...
Someone told be there is inbuilt function for this in visual studio..

Answer (score 0):

You should never roll your own authentication module. Use ASP.NET SimpleMembership instead. It has built in support for roles.

Comment: If i use built-in role module then i also have to use the built in authentication module of VS2012..is there any manual method by which i can make roles?

Comment: There's a [`Roles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Roles(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is contains a complete API for working with the roles.